Why can't I copy files from a Windows 10 PC to a shared NAS device (Zyxel NAS 540)?
Why can't I copy files from a Windows 10 PC to a shared NAS device (Zyxel NAS 540)?
Please note:

I am only trying to copy one file at a time.
I can use the same user name and password to copy files to the same NAS with a Windows 11 system.
The files being copied are new files PDF or DOCX or TXT.
The files being copied are usually less than 1 MB.
There are no existing files with the same name.
There are no hidden or system or hidden system files being copied.
If there are files on the NAS I can delete them using both the Windows 10 and Windows 11 systems.
If there are files on the NAS I can move them using both the Windows 10 and Windows 11 systems.
I have tried just accessing via a network share and via mapped drive the copy still fails.
I have re-created the user on the NAS to see if this has any effect. (The copy still fails on the windows 10 system.)
I have tried installing SMB 1.0 and SMB direct on the Windows 10 system. (The copy still fails on the windows 10 system.)
There are other users (Windows 11 and Ubuntu OS) who are not having this problem.

When I drag and drop the files I am told:

The destination already has a file named "insertfilenamehere"

I and then choose to (a) replace the file (b) skip the file (c) compare the files.
When I chose (a) replace the file I get told

"You need permission to perform this action"

A file called "insertfilenamehere" of 0 bytes is created.
I have looked at these questions, but these do not help me solve my problem.

Asked whether or not to replace files when copying to an empty destination?
Windows 10 - Copy files asks to overwrite files

As far as I know, the issue is something to do with Windows 10.
Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Does using copy from a command prompt work? (And don't forget to uninstall SMB 1.0.)

Make sure the NAS itself is updated if possible. Issues with the samba service or its cache can cause similar behavior. Does it work if you use cmd or powershell, like copy "c:\folder\myfile.txt" "\\NAS\share\myfolder\"?

Doing a copy or xcopy gives "access denied" error but a 0 bytes file is created. I have uninstalled the SMB 1.0 :-)  I can do a save as from inside the PDF reader or notepad to the NAS without any error.

It's almost certainly a bug with the nas. Do you currently use a username/password to connect? You might be able to try setting one up or connecting with a different one, and see if that gets around whatever issue it's having. Otherwise, I suggest looking into updating the firmware to 5.21 if it's not already there

So it seems a placeholder file is being created at the outset of the copy and then that placeholder conflicts with the "rest" of the file being copied over. If you create/place another file with the same name and then try to copy over that, do you get the same issue? I agree this appears to be a bug in the NAS code. Yes, Win10 may be having some impact in HOW it copies, but the system generating the error, the NAS, is the one that is likely the root cause.

@CptWhale the nas is at Firmware version:V5.21(AATB.9)  There is an upgrade but it keeps failing at 9%

. @music2myear A copy over and retry copy also fails. Although I think it is the NAS the fact that I can copy from windows 11 and Ubuntu makes me wonder.

I did a firmware update of the NAS to fix this.
TLDR
I made a copy of everything on the NAS
I then did a full factory reset
Action: Press the RESET button until you hear two beeps. After the second beep, and continue pressing the button for around five more seconds, then release it. You will hear three quick beeps after you release the button.
If you do not hear three beeps, it did not reset
Result: All the NAS settings are set to the factory default configuration. All settings you have configured on the NAS, including IP address, password, user accounts, groups, shares, and so on, will be reset to the factory defaults. In my case, it did not remove the files on the HDD.
I downloaded the firmware update separately and did the firmware update via a local download.
The firmware update was successful. After rebooting and reconfiguring the NAS, I am now able to copy files to it.

While it could have been a bug the firmware update fixed, what likely fixed it was the factory reset, which would have reset the ACLs on the share since users/groups and shares were deleted. If it occurs again, check the ACLs on the NAS for the share, as well as from Windows via icacls "\\<server>\<share>" or going to the Advanced Security properties via Properties → Tab: Security → Advanced Security

I am experiencing the same issue using Zyxel NAS542 and a Windows 10 PC, both upgraded to the latest versions. After running a packet capture while trying to upload a small file I saw the NT_STATUS_EAS_NOT_SUPPORTED error sent by the NAS. A quick search lead me to the fix: ea support = yes added to the global section in the samba config on the NAS and the smbd service restarted. Based on the samba documentation this is the default configuration, but looks like this in not the case for the samba version in the NAS. Too bad that this file gets automatically rebuild so for a "permanent" solution a cron job could be created to check the samba config and add the line if it is missing. I will try sending a email to Zyxel about this.

From reading the answer, I not sure if adding ea support = yes was a temporary fix to the problem or not. Consider editing the answer to clarify that.

It is temporary because the file gets overwritten by the Zyxel scripts when a realated configuration is changed in the web interface or after a restart. Up untill then the issue described in this thread is fixed.

Thanks for this info.  I will need to try this as I keep having this issue as I do power down the raid overnight. Right now I either copy the file to my Windows 11 pc and then to the raid or use the web interface to copy the files.

Meanwhile, I recieved a response from the Zyxel support saying that they will forward my complaint to the related team but most likely the issue will not be fixed since the device is out of support.
I spend some  time tring to find a way to add the line peramanently to the samba config but failed.
In the past I used a third party repository created by the user Mijzelf in the Zyxel forums which provided some packages including a newer version of samba which whould have worked for longer term solution but this repository seems to be gone.
